# Differentiating between "blank input" and having a zero value as the actual input

Tags: java, if-statement

Beginner coder here. I'm trying to differentiate when a user inputs a value and does not input a value.

Right now the integer variable = 0 when there is no specified value input by the user.

But if the user inputs 0 as their variable, I need it to be different.

```
if(exam1Input == 0){
    exam1Per = 0;}
if(exam2Input == 0){
    exam2Per = 0;}
if(finalExamInput == 0){
    finalExamPer = 0;}
if(labsInput == 0){
    labsPer = 0;}
if(projectsInput == 0){
    projectsPer = 0;}
if(quizzesInput == 0){
    quizzesPer = 0;}
if(attendanceInput == 0){
    attendancePer = 0;}
```

I did this multibranch if statement to covert the value of the percentage grade weights to zero if the input was zero(i.e. no input at all).

However I come across a problem of when the user inputs "0" as their actual grade. I can't let the percentage weight be 0, I still need it to be the certain grade percentage.

e.g. if their test average is 0, i still need to calculate their percentage based on the grade 0.

So how could I be more specific and able to differentiate between a missing input versus an actual input?

I want zero to be the actual grade not as a missing input.

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve that `int`?

Comment: Why don't you use -1 as default?

Comment: Terrible! The code you proposed is terrible! Its cyclomatic complexity is unbelievable high and without a reason! Please, change the logic of your code.

Comment: @acornagl rather than ranting at OP, calling the code "Terrible" (twice) and "unbelievable" and using technical jargon, how about you make some suggestions as to how to do it better? We were all beginners once.

Comment: If using int you can use -1 or any negative value as 'No imput'. You can algo use Integer (null means no input)

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to use a different default value that would be invalid input from the user. e.g:

```
static final int NO_INPUT = -1;

int exam1Input = NO_INPUT;

/**Prompt the user for input somewhere around here*/

if(exam1Input == 0) ...
```

Now, exam1Input  will only be 0 if the user explicitly made it 0, and -1 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Or, use an OptionalInt instead of an int. This sort of scenario is what they are for.

```
OptionalInt input = OptionalInt.empty();
// input = Optional.of(someValue); if set
If (input.isPresent()) {
    int i = input.getAsInt();
    // use the value
}
```